# Is there a way to get the latest added items to a NSArrayController?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there a way to get the latest added items to a NSArrayController ?

I would like to select the new items after adding them.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell the array controller to do this:

```
arrayController.selectsInsertedObjects = YES;
```

This is the default setting, so perhaps you're looking for something else?